# How to vertically align the baseline of a hyperref form Text Field with surrounding text?

Tags: hyperref, vertical-alignment, forms

I try to vertically align hyperref's TextField such that the filled text is level with the surrounding text, for any text size. The accepted solution to [How to align text in Textfield form to the bottom rather than the top](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325826/how-to-align-text-in-textfield-form-to-the-bottom-rather-than-the-to) suggests to down-shift the TextField by 0.25\baselineskip. This number, first of all, is not quite right to bring down the filled-in text to level with the surrounding text. Secondly, this number has to change if the height of the TextField is modified (personally, I prefer to use a TextField of height=12pt for a 10pt font to avoid overlapping TextFields on consecutive lines). Here comes a MWE to illustrate the problem:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\baseline}{% %% helper to show text baseline 
\noindent%
\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule{\linewidth}{0.1pt}}}


\renewcommand*{\DefaultOptionsofText}{print,charsize=10pt,borderwidth=1pt,width=8ex,name=mytextfield}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\baseline%
Leading text, \raisebox{0\baselineskip}{\TextField{field neither scaled nor shifted:}}, trailing text

\baseline%
Leading text, \raisebox{-.25\baselineskip}{\TextField{field not scaled, but shifted:}}, trailing text

\baseline%
Leading text,  \raisebox{0\baselineskip}{\TextField[height=12pt]{field scaled, but not shifted:}}, trailing text 

\baseline%
Leading text, \raisebox{-.25\baselineskip}{\TextField[height=12pt]{field scaled and shifted:}}, trailing text

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

None of the Textfields entries is precisely vertically aligned with the surrounding text (nor its label, for that matter). So my question is: By how much does one have to shift a TextField of arbitrary height to have the filled-in text sit *exactly* on the external baseline? I have consulted the hyperref manual but couldn't understand enough of it to come up with a general, let alone elegant, solution.